# display the fisrt category of the menu immediately after opening the app

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, expo, react-native-flatlist

My App is Cafe App and when I open the app the home screen shows up with all data of the menu mixed and display together. So what I wanna do is that when the user open the app the home screen displays firstly the first category of data by default which is coffee and then the user has the options to choose other category by clicking on category button.

Home.js

```
const Home =()=>{

  const [categories, setCategories] = useState(categoryData)
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState(null)
  const [products, setProducts] = useState (ProductData)

    // category option function
    function renderCategories(){
      return(
        <View>
            <FlatList 
              horizontal
              showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
              data={categories}
              keyExtractor={item=>item.id}
              renderItem={({item,index})=>{
                return(
                  <TouchableOpacity 
                     onPress={()=>onSelecteCategory(item)}>

                    {/*Images*/}

                    <Image 
                       source={item.icon}
                       resizeMode="contain"
                     />
                  </TouchableOpacity>
                )
              }}
            
            />

        </View>
      )
    }

    //Filter Products

    function onSelecteCategory(category){
      let productList = ProductData.filter(a => a.categories.includes(category.id))
      setProducts(productList)

      setSelected(category)
    }
 

     // function display all products data
    function renderProduct(){
      return(
        <View>
          <Carousel 
            containerCustomStyle={{overflow:'visible'}}
            data={products}
            loop={true}
            renderItem={({item})=>
            <ProductCard 
             sharedElementPrefix='Home'
            item={item} 
            onPress={()=> navigation.navigate('ProductDetails',
            {item:item,sharedElementPrefix:'Home'} )}
            />}
            firstItem={2}
            inactiveSlideOpacity={0.75}
            inactiveSlideScale={0.77}
            sliderWidth={400}
            itemWidth={240}
        
          
          />
      )
    }
```

I wanna only coffee category displays first as main product of the home screen and then the user can use the category button option to move on. any idea please help me thank you